# Does base64 image conversion supports to android version 11?

Tags: android, file-upload, base64, android-version

I had used base64 for image conversion but for some Samsung mobiles of having android version 11 it was not converting and image was not uploading to server. But after clear cache, clear data and reinstalling the application images are uploading finely to server. Can someone let me know how this happened?

Comment: `had used base64 for image conversion `?? Impossible i would say. You cannot convert an image using base64. With base64 you can encode data. Later you can decode the stuff and get the data back. That data has not changed.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.